# Scikit Learn-MultinomialNB for text classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How to Calculate FPR, TPR, AUC, roc_curve for multi class text classification.

I have used following code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect=CountVectorizer()
vect.fit(X_train.values.astype('U'))
X_train_dtm=vect.transform(X_train.values.astype('U'))
X_test_dtm=vect.transform(X_test)
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
nb = MultinomialNB()
y_score=nb.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
y_pred_class = nb.predict(X_test_dtm)
```

Every thing runs fine till here.
but as soon as I am using following code this gives error.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, roc_auc_score
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(5):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
print ("ROC value is:",roc_auc["micro"])
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    

File "C:/Users/saurabh/PycharmProjects/getting_started/own_code.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_prob))    

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py", line 260, in roc_auc_score
    sample_weight=sample_weight) Accuracy by this: 0.910536779324    

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\base.py", line 81, in _average_binary_score
    raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type)) 

ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

`roc_curve` doesnt support multiclass format. You have to calculate for binary class.

But to calculate FPR, TPR you can use `confusion_matrix`

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
y_score = np.argmax(y_score, axis=1)
c = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_score)
TNR = float(c[0][0])
TPR = float(c[1][1])
FNR = float(c[1][0])
FPR = float(c[0][1])
```

Here's a simple example to binarize

```
for i in range(5):
    yt_bin = [1 if x == i else 0 for x in y_test[:, i]]
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(yt_bin, y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
```

Comment: Thanks Ishant for reply but still I am getting following errors- TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got estimator MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)

Comment: see my edits. You may also need to convert input to numpy array for the second part.

Comment: Hi! I tried with your suggested code but I am still not getting results. What am I doing wrong? Thanks! at this line-y_score = np.argmax(y_score, axis=1) I am getting-ValueError: axis(=1) out of bounds

Comment: make sure `y_test/y_score` are numpy array. And your previous errors are not related to this answer

Comment: `y_score` is the entire fitted `MultinomialNB` object the way it's currently defined.  Use `y_pred_class` instead (although I'm not sure you want `argmax`...try `confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_class)` without the `argmax` transformation).

Comment: still I am getting error -ValueError: multiclass format is not supported

Comment: any resource? which can help with detail discussion in the direction of multi class text classification.  I have gone through the sklearn documentation but when I am using above mentioned code this gives error.